# Passing an integer stored with mmap to GTK

Tags: c, gtk3, mmap

### EDIT

This question ended up being two problems packed into one.  Yet, I cannot delete the question.  The scope of the original question regarding pointers was solved by @David Ranieri.  The mmap/fork/gtk problem will be the scope of a new question and will not be addressed here.

---

I want to print a value I have stored in memory in a GTK window.  The integer must be stored using `mmap` to be retained during a fork elsewhere in the code.  I cannot reference this memory mapped address from GTK without getting a SegFault.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a better way?

### My current strategy:

- Reserve memory for an `int` with `mmap` at `*VAL`
- Fork process, one half modifies `VAL` the other half runs GTK
- Pass `*VAL` to app in userdata slot
- The userdata now called `localval` in `activate()`
- Print the value at address `localval` by converting from `gpointer` to `int`.

### MWE (this causes a segfault, run at your own risk):

```
/*
 * MMAP Variable SegFault
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer *localval) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    // Button Containers
    GtkWidget *button_box_quit;
    // Buttons
    GtkWidget *exit_button;
    // Text
    GtkWidget *text_status;
    
    // Define Window, dynamic size for screen.
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
    
    // Define Button Boxes.
    button_box_quit = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    
    // Define Exit Button, put it in a box, put box in window
    exit_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Exit");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), exit_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box_quit);

    // Connect signals to buttons
    g_signal_connect_swapped (exit_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    
    // Define text status
    char msg[32]={0};
    // The "print" line
    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(*localval));
    text_status = gtk_label_new(msg);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), text_status);
    
    //Activate!
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    
    int *VAL = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int *ABORT = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == 0) {
        while(!*ABORT) {
            printf("%d\n", *VAL);
            *VAL = *VAL + 1;
            usleep(1000000);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        // The passing line
        g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), (gpointer *)*VAL);
        status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref (app);
        *ABORT = 1;
    }
    *ABORT = 1;
    return status;
}
```

---

In a non-working alternative to this code, I tried changing the print line to:

```
g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", &GPOINTER_TO_INT(*localval));
```

But the compiler thinks I want to use the <kbd>&</kbd> as a comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a dereferenced pointer (a value) to a function expecting a pointer:

```
int *VAL = ...;
...
g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), (gpointer *)*VAL);
```

switch to

```
g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), VAL); // Do not use a wrong cast (void **)
```

also, `gpointer` is an alias of `void *`, using `gpointer *data` you get a `void **data`, not what you want, so

```
static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer *localval) {
```

should be

```
static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer localval) { // without *
```

finally, to print the value of the pointer use

```
g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);
```

Comment: While this prints something, it is not meaningful.  The GTK window shows "val = -1225920512".

Comment: Have you tried `g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *localval);` without the `GPOINTER_TO_INT`? Notice that you are not casting using `GINT_TO_POINTER` to pass the signal (obviously because the var is already a pointer) and this could be a problem, they must be used in conjunction.

Comment: I have.  With this change and the <kbd>&</kbd> in ``g_signal_connect`` I get the same nonsense value.  With the change but without <kbd>&</kbd> it prints "val = 1", but it never updates like it should.  Additionally, I get a string formatting error to replace ``%d`` with something to match "‘gpointer’ {aka ‘void *’}".

Comment: Sorry, I mean `g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);`

Comment: I had not tried that.  It appears to behave the same way as my previous comment.

Comment: You have an edit, there is also a change in the call of `g_signal_connect`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211890/discussion-between-wesh-and-david-ranieri).